# how to get data from relation laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

i have function ini my controller like this :

```
public function get_user_order() 
{
    $user = auth()->user()->orders()->with('products')->get();
    $order = $user->products->name;
    dd($order);
}
```

i want to get logged in user order history.

this is my user model:

```
class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
public function orders() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
}
```

this is my order model :

```
class Order extends Model
{
  public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
}
}
```

the problem is how can u get the product name from this relation ?
please help me im newb, sorry for my broken english.

Comment: A `User` has many orders, so `$user->orders` is a collection, even if there is just 1 order.  To see the products, you have to iterate over all orders.

Comment: thanks for explain my problem, now I know what I have to do.